# Simple Datetime parse issue cross-browser

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

Can somebody explain why parsing a date results in different dates in Chrome and Firefox...? I must misunderstand something...?!?

```
// this js line gives a different result in Chrome than in Firefox:
alert(new Date('2016-01-01T00:00:00'));
```

Chrome:
Fri Jan 01 2016 **01**:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)

Firefox:
Fri Jan 01 2016 **00**:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adnd48zo/1/

Comment: Is the time alerted based on your browser settings?

Comment: I get `Fri Jan 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Hora padrão de GMT)` on chrome btw.

Comment: For some reason, your copy of Firefox seems to think that Western Europe time offset in February is `+0100` rather than zero. Are you in UK or Portugal?

Answer (score 0):

When setting a date without specifying the time zone, JavaScript will use the browser's time zone.